# Expressing a matrix product of a matrix and a hadamard product as a hadamard product of matrix products

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, signal-processing, hadamard-product

I have a matrix $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times K}$ which undergoes a transform (specifically the ZCA whitening transform) represented by $\mathbf{W}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$ to form $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{W}\mathbf{X}$. Now the issue is that most of my algorithm is in the whitened coordinate i.e. I am working with $\mathbf{Y}$. However, there is one specific part of the algorithm where I need to calculate $\mathbf{Z}=\mathbf{X}\circ\mathbf{\Phi}$ i.e. a Hadamard product. Would be there be a way for me to get to $\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{W}\mathbf{Z}$ directly from $\mathbf{Y}$ without going back to $\mathbf{X}$?

I have
\begin{align}
q_{ij} &= \sum_{k}w_{ik}z_{kj}\\
&=\sum_{k}w_{ik}(x_{kj}\phi_{kj})\\
&=\sum_{k}w_{ik}x_{kj}\phi_{kj}\\
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
y_{ij} &= \sum_{k}w_{ik}x_{kj}
\end{align}
but I couldn't quite go anywhere from here due to the summation involved

I have considered this as well
\begin{align}
\newcommand{vec}[1]{\operatorname{vec}(#1)}
\vec{\mathbf{W}\mathbf{Z}}
&=(\mathbf{I}_N \otimes \mathbf{W})\vec{\mathbf{Z}}\\
&=(\mathbf{I}_N \otimes \mathbf{W})\vec{\mathbf{X}\circ\mathbf{\Phi}}\\
&=(\mathbf{I}_N \otimes \mathbf{W})(\vec{\mathbf{X}}\circ\vec{\mathbf{\Phi}})\\
\end{align}
but there isn't much else I can do to reform $\mathbf{Y}$ from there either.

Comment: Why have you ruled out the obvious, i.e. $\,Z=\Phi\circ(W^{-1}Y)$ ? It seems odd that you are willing to work with gigantic Kronecker products, but are adverse to a simple matrix inverse.

Comment: @greg Unfortunately, the matrix inverse creates a huge precision issue in MATLAB and I have to rule it out.

Comment: If $\bf Y$ is supposed to be the matrix $\bf X$ after change of basis by $\mathbf W$, Then the equation is $\bf Y = WXW^{-1}$, not $Y = WX$. When applying to a vector $v$ in the new coordinate system, you first use $\bf W^{-1}$ to transform it to the old coordinate system, apply $\bf X$ to the result, then use $\bf W$ to transform the output back to the new coordinate system.

Comment: @PaulSinclair ZCA whitening is a well-known transformation. Each column $x_k$ of the matrix $X$ is transformed into a new vector by the action of the whitening matrix, i.e. $y_k=Wx_k$. [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117427) has lots of interesting details.